# How are storage pointers implemented in the EVM layer?

Tags: evm, storage, opcode

I'm trying to understand how storage pointers work. From looking at the ethereumjs-vm implementation it seems that the actual value is returned from SLOAD. Does the compiler handle the 'pointer' functionality? (ie. calls SSTORE if its modified).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the compiler handles the pointer functionality. You do not need to explicitly de-reference a storage pointer when you want to write to or read from the storage location it points to.

I think the fact that they are called pointers is very confusing. It reminds me of C pointers, but storage pointers in Solidity are much more like C++ or PHP references than they are like C pointers.

**Solidity pointers:**

```
uint256[] public a;
constructor() public
{
    a.push(1);
    test(a);
}
function test(uint256[] storage b) private
{
    b[0] = 7;
    // a[0] is now 7
}
```

**C++ references (similar to Solidity pointers):**

```
int a = 1;
int& b = a;
b = 7;
// a is now 7
```

**PHP references (also similar to Solidity pointers):**

```
$a = 1;
$b = &$a;
$b = 7;
// a is now 7
```

**C pointers (*very different from* Solidity pointers):**

```
int a = 1;
int* b = &a;
b = 7;
// a is now still 1
```

Comment: "the fact that they are called pointers is very confusing" <-- Where do you see them being called pointers? I thought the Solidity documentation called them references.

Comment: @smarx Two excerpts from the Solidity documentation: "This is of course not the case if storage pointers are passed as function arguments as in the case for the high-level libraries." "Multi-dimensional memory arrays are pointers to memory arrays."

Comment: Ugh. I agree that "references" is a much better term. Maybe a bug or pull request is in order.